# Why does python os.path.isfile return false on windows, for only a specific directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7

On windows 7, when I run this Python 2.7 code, "NOT file" prints, but the file is there, its not read only, the folder is not read only, none of its parents are read only.

```
if os.path.exists('D:\testfiles\mysub\GraphiteController.js'):
    print "IS file"
else:
    print "NOT file"
sys.exit(1)
```

If I move the file to `d:\myother directory`, prints "IS file".
If I move the file to `d:\testfiles directory`, prints "NOT file".

I tried this on another windows machine, same problem. Very strange.

Answer (score 9):

It's because '\t' is a tab character. Use forward slashes in your paths or use raw strings:

```
if os.path.exists('D:/testfiles/mysub/GraphiteController.js'):
```

or

```
if os.path.exists(r'D:\testfiles\mysub\GraphiteController.js'):
```

Comment: Good catch! I often forget to use raw strings when dealing with file paths and run into the same problems.

Comment: Why this happens: http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html?highlight=windows%20slash#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash

Comment: @alanjds: that's a different issue; here there's no backslash to end the string...

Comment: :) Not pointing to this part. Pointing to the "should escape backslashes, but will not get beautiful" and than to "you can use forward slashes too, and Python will convert for you"

Comment: Python actually doesn't convert them. Windows accepts them at the syscall level.

Comment: Or `'D:\\testfiles\\mysub\\GraphiteController.js'`, although the raw string solution is best.